# ¿Cómo añadir columnas en un fichero CSV?

Tags: bash, awk, procesamiento-de-texto

Me encuentro realizando un cambio de texto de un archivo a otro en Bash.

Lo que necesito cambiar como tal es esto

```
created_at,field1,field2
2022-03-02 00:57:03,20.1 ,36
2022-03-02 01:07:03,20.2 ,36
2022-03-02 01:17:03,20.1 ,36.5
```

a esto

```
created_at,field1,field2,field3
2022-03-02 00:57:03,2022-03-02 00:57:03,20.1 ,36 ,
2022-03-02 01:07:03,2022-03-02 01:07:03,20.2 ,36 ,
2022-03-02 01:17:03,2022-03-02 01:17:03,20.2 ,36.5 ,
```

en resumen, necesito añadir un campo mas de manera automática:

- en la primera linea, que se llame field3, pero no quiero tener problemas con los espacios.
- además necesito clonar el primer campo de cada línea, para tenerlo dos veces.
- por ultimo, añadir una coma en todas las líneas menos en la primera.

He estado mirando con el sed y con awk para cortar por comas, pero no entiendo como puedo hacer por ejemplo, que solo al final de la primera linea me agregue ",field3" y luego siga leyendo, o como añadir una coma al final de cada linea. ¿Alguien me puede ayudar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con Awk es bastante rápido:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{OFS=","} NR==1{print $0, "field3";next} {print $0, $0, ""}' a
created_at,field1,field2,field3
2022-03-02 00:57:03,20.1 ,36,2022-03-02 00:57:03,20.1 ,36,
2022-03-02 01:07:03,20.2 ,36,2022-03-02 01:07:03,20.2 ,36,
2022-03-02 01:17:03,20.1 ,36.5,2022-03-02 01:17:03,20.1 ,36.5,
```

Con `OFS=","` le decimos que el carácter que separa registros es la coma y luego añadimos o bien "field3" en la primera línea, o bien duplicamos en el resto de líneas.

Comment: Muy útil, muchas gracias. Solucionado